# Testing a method call with arguments using RSpec and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this Rails API and I'm trying to test two actions in my controller. The first one is supposed to call the second one. How can I do this using RSpec?

These are the Actions:

```
def method1
    (...)
    method2(@example_var)
end

def method2(id)
    (...)
end
```

So far, I've tried this, unsuccessfully

```
describe "#method1" do
    it "calls the method2 with id" do
        Rails::logger.info "Testing METHOD1"
        var = Parent.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:valid_attributes))
        get :method1, :id => var.id

        Parent.should_receive(:method2).with(var.id)
        Parent.method2
    end
end
```

Any help?

EDIT: If information is not enough, I will gladly provide more.

Comment: 1. Please include more of the controller. Is the class `Parent`?
2. I think you'll need to set the expectation (should_receive) before you perform the action you expect to trigger it (calling get :method1).
3. Why are you calling method2 explicitly?

Comment: I solved my issue in the meantime, but since I'm pretty new to Rails I was messing up everything. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly an answer, but this was what I intended and the solution to it :) Hope this can help someone who needs it

The test:

```
describe "GET #method1" do
    it "gets a parent by :id and redirect_to #method2" do
        Rails::logger.info "Testing METHOD1 with redirect to METHOD2"
        vars = Parent.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:valid_params))

        expect redirect_to('method2/' + vars.field1 + '/' + vars.field2 + '/' + vars.field3)
    end
end
```

The controller:

```
def close
    (...)
    redirect_to :controller => 'Parents', :action => 'method2', :field1 => @parent[:field1], :field2 => @parent[:field2], :field3 => @parent[:field3]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `method2` is not called on `Parent`. It will be called on the controller instance
2. Expectation should be set before the call is made
3. Is `method2` a private method? If its an action, you should redirect to the action instead of calling the method.

But if you want to set an expection on the `method2` call, do the following

```
describe "#method1" do
    it "calls the method2 with id" do
        Rails::logger.info "Testing METHOD1"
        var = Parent.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:valid_attributes))
        @controller.should_receive(:method2).with(var.id)
        get :method1, :id => var.id
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I've already solved the issue. Read my comment above. I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation yet :(